# How do I replace a text string with a number, based on a key word contained in the cell

Tags: string, spss, text-extraction

I have a string variable with short text strings. I want to replace all the text strings with numbers based on key words contained inside the individual cells.

Example: Some cells states "I like cats", while others "I dont like the smell of wet dog".

I want to assign the value 1 to all cells containing the word cat, and the number 2 to all cells containing the word dog.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will put 1 in NewVar when "cat" appears in OldVar, 2 for "dog", 3 for "mouse":

```
do repeat wrd="cat" "dog" "mouse"/val= 1 2 3.
  if index(OldVar, wrd)>0 NewVar=val.
end repeat.
```

This is only good if there will never be a cat AND a dog in the same sentence. If you do have such cases you should go this way:

```
do repeat wrd="cat" "dog" "mouse"/NewVar=cat dog mouse.
  compute NewVar=char.index(OldVar, wrd)>0.
end repeat.
```

This will create a new variable for each of the possible words, putting 1 in cases where the word appears in OldVar, 0 when it doesn't.

Comment: You answer is even better than the one I found, thank you!

Comment: If you have problems with capital letters in your text, you can use the UPCASE function like you did in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to open a syntax window and enter this command:

```
COMPUTE newvar=CHAR.INDEX(UPCASE(VAR1),"ABCD")>0
```

newvar is the name of the new variable.
VAR1 is the name of the variable to be searched.
ABCD is the text to be searched for. **NOTE**: This must be in CAPITAL letters.

newvar will recieve a value of 1 if the text is found.